# Django, can't transmit user login status among pages after register and login

Tags: django, session, authentication, request

I use custom user model and config the settings file correctly.

this is reg view

```
def user_reg(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.RegForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        name = data['name']
        password = data['password']
        MyUser.objects.create_user(name,password)
        user = authenticate(username=name, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return render_to_response('common/success.html',{'config':config}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

else:
    form = forms.RegForm()
return render_to_response('common/reg.html', {'config': config,'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in common/reg.html here is

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{{ user.name }}
{% else %}
not user
{% endif %}
<a href="index">index page link</a>
```

and the web page show the new user's name. it is ok.
but when I visit the web index page directly, or through the link.
here is the index view , it is decoratored

```
@login_required
def index(request):
    show something...
```

now I can't see the index page but redirected to the login page. 
I login just now ,why go to the login page here??????

database migration is ok.

app and middware

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'account',
'forum',
'uuidfield',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'debug_toolbar',)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',)
```

here is custom user model,just like the django doc :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, name, password=None,nick_name=None,gender=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    if not name:
        raise ValueError(u'name error')

    user = self.model(name=name)
    if nick_name:
        user.nick_name = nick_name
    else:
        user.nick_name = name
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, name, password):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(name=name)
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

uuid = UUIDField(auto=True, hyphenate=True, primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)  
nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
gender = models.NullBooleanField(choices=GENDER, default=None)

objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'name'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

class Meta:
    db_table = 'account_user'

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.name

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.name

def __unicode__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.name

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```

Comment: Can you post your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank u. Added the app and middleware now

Comment: Do you use a custom manager for your user? If so, post the `create_user` method.

Comment: And probably the model itself, too.

Comment: The only thing suspicious there is the UUID as pk. Might be a bug with Django. Can you print the value of `user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)` after you call login?

Comment: login(request, user)
    print user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
and the console shows "4115dce7-27d1-4ab8-8a7d-2e389e51c643
"
it is the uuid field value , it's ok.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I changed the view, delete the second view. Use render_to_response and requestcontext, the success page can show new user's name . But other page is bad. Please have a look at my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My God!!!!!!!
django-uuid have a bug
when field's attr 'hyphenate' is true . the uuid is 36 length , but the value get from session is still 32 length . so the cookie can't match session
so is it!

Answer (score 0):

The secound view should return:

```
render_to_response('common/success.html',{'config':config,'next':next_url}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

(you have missed `context_instance`).

Comment: I delete the second view and directly goto the success page in the reg view.
And I change the code , please have a look ,thank u